# Problem in using comparator function [c++]

Tags: c++, comparator

while using the comparator function which is given below I get a segmentation fault:-

```
    class Solution {
    public:
static bool comp( pair<int,pair<int,int> > &a, pair<int,pair<int,int> > &b )
{
    if(a.first <= b.first)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int t1(vector<int>& nums, int target)
{
    vector< pair<int,pair<int,int> > > sum_of_two;
    int n=nums.size();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            sum_of_two.push_back( make_pair( nums[i]+nums[j] ,make_pair(i,j) ) ); 
        }
    }
    sort(sum_of_two.begin(),sum_of_two.end() ,comp );
    return 1;  
}
    };
```

but the comp function below works fine, I am not able to find why?

```
      static bool comp( pair<int,pair<int,int> > &a, pair<int,pair<int,int> > &b )
      {
            if(a.first < b.first)
                  return 1;
             else
                  return 0;
      }
```

Comment: https://testing.googleblog.com/2017/11/obsessed-with-primitives.html

Comment: Is the seg fault definitely happening on your call to `sort()`?

Comment: Also, it should be noted that `t1()` does not return a value, but it expects to return an `int`

Comment: the seg fault is happening on sort() function

Comment: The "comparison" function is actually as ordering function, and yours says that any element should be ordered before itself, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The two comparisons are different.  The first does not implement a *strict weak ordering*, because if `a.first == b.first` then both `comp(a, b)` and `comp(b, a)` will return true.  Since this violates the requirements of the comparison function, the behavior is Undefined.

The fix is easy:  change the test to

```
if(a.first < b.first)
```

so that it returns `false` when the two values are equal.

Comment: if we use if(a.first < b.first) then both comp(a,b) and comp(b,a) will return false when a.first=b.first wil that be correct?

Comment: @vikasyadav Yes.  You'd expect `2<2` to be false when `2==2`, right?

Comment: @vikasyadav "a is not ordered before b" and "b is not ordered before a" can both be true at the same time (for instance if `a == b` or if they can't be ordered at all). "a is ordered before b" and "b is ordered before a" can't be true at the same time.